# Why am I getting errors when trying to run Get-Transportconfig in a Powershell session?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to run **Powershell** to invoke **Set-TransportConfig** on my Exchange mailbox.
Windows Powershell ISE is running elevated as admin.

**I am able to connect to Exchange:**

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName
```

**When I attempt to run this command:**

```
Get-TransportConfig -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled
```

**I get the following error:**

> Get-TransportConfig : The term 'Get-TransportConfig' is not recognized
> as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
> the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-TransportConfig -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-TransportConfig:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

**If I run the following:**

```
get-command *transportconfig*
```

It does not return any commands:.

**I've tried running:**

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

It does not return any errors or results (Does that mean it's correctly installed?)

Why can't I run the **Get-TransportConfig** command? What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing an additional library?

Comment: `Get-TransportConfig` doesn't appear as a command in [ExchangeOnlineManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps).  It looks to be part of the [ExchangePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps) module instead.

Comment: @boxdog - I've installed/imported ExchangeOnlineManagement (at least it looks like I did) and I still get the same error for GetTransportConfig. How do I verify that ExchangeOnlineManagement  is correctly installed? Why am I still getting the error?

Comment: As I mentioned, that cmdlet is not listed as part of the module you installed - see the link I provided.  The other module I linked to _does_ list that cmdlet.  Did you try using the other module?  Sorry, I don't have a system I can check this myself at the moment, so I'm just going by the documentation.

Comment: Same issue. Definitely not straightforward.

Comment: Same for me.  Link above provides no info on how to install in powershell.  I am using on a Mac but I'm guess the commands to install this library are out there but I can't find them either.